# React lifting states up and down multiple times to filter components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Component diagram:

```
"Main"
|--"Side"--"CategoryPicker"
|
|--"ItemBoard"
```

`categoryPicker` gets the chosen value.

```
    const filterResultHandler = (e) => {
    props.onFilterChange(e.target.value);}
    ...
    onChange={filterResultHandler}
```

And lift up the value to `Side`.

```
   const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState("all");    
   const onFilterChangeHandler = () => { props.onPassData(setFilterState);};

   ...

   <CategoryPicker selected={filterState} onFilterChange={onFilterChangeHandler} />
```

Then I repeat to lift value to the `Main`.
(Up to this point I have console.log the value and it seemed OK.)

```
  const [recData, setRecData] = useState("all");

  const onFilterChangeHandler = (passedData) => {
  setRecData(passedData);};

  <Side onPassData={onFilterChangeHandler} selected={recData} />
```

Then pass it down to `Itemboard` as a prop.

```
<ItemBoard items={items} recData={recData} />
```

In `ItemBoard` I am trying to filter the array then compare to later map it and display filtered components.

```
 const filteredProducts = props.items.filter((product) => {
 return (product.cat.toString() === props.recData)})

 {filteredProducts.map((product, index) => (
 <Item cat={product.cat} />
 ))}
```

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`Side`) while rendering a different component (`Main`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Main`

Where am I loosing my logic?
PS.
Trying to focus on understanding how lifting up and passing props works, not looking for better solutions to the problem right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the bad setState use in this code:

```
const [recData, setRecData] = useState("all");
    
      const onFilterChangeHandler = (passedData) => {
      setRecData(passedData);};
    
      <Side onPassData={onFilterChangeHandler} selected={recData} />
```

why you are passing this `selected={recData}` data again to Side component, you are updating the state of Main component from Side component and passing the `selected={recData}` again, remove this and try again

Comment: Thank you very much.I have tried to pass selected item back to component to provide "value={selected}" for some reason.